# Offline-first collaborative real-time web-app

Tags: reactjs, architecture, backend, offline

I currently have an Electron ReactJS application on hand that uses CouchDB as its backend for syncing and real-time updates. I have been tasked with "porting" the backend of this application to an existing webserver. The goal is to use the existing permission management and business logic implementations. At the same time the intent is to refactor the data structures as the data is heavily relational in nature. That said, personally, I would keep the app on CouchDB as it full-fills the main "offline-first and real-time" requirements and just add the missing authentication and permission layers, but management wants otherwise.

The port would be using an existing web server (running Play Framework with Scala) and a relational database (MySQL). I have been scavenging the web for a good existing solution. The "simple" solution that came to my mind sounds tedious and like I'm reinventing the wheel. My idea was to create an API and on top of it also send real-time updates to the users to which a change is relevant via web sockets. For state management on the client I would use Redux + Redux Offline.  While this would work, this would require a lot of manual wiring of CRUDs on the backend server and the according requests and mutations on the client.

I have taken a look at AWS AppSync, Meteor.js and Apollo. AWS AppSync sounds like exactly what I could use, but it relies on the database being accessible to it, which is not an option due to my DB instance being on premise. From Apollo, the client part sounds like an option I could go with and then use [Sangria](https://sangria-graphql.org) on the backend. I suppose I could also drop the idea of Redux and use Apollo's "local state", although this requires more thought as I'm not familiar with it.

All of the latter solutions involve GraphQL. While this would still require quite some work on the backend, the communication itself between the frontend and backend would be simpler to handle.

In my case where the use of an existing backend server is a must, are there any more elegant solutions for offline-first collaborative real-time apps? Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi,  the question is mostly seeking opinion on a software or a solution. While it may be a valid question, chances are that it will get closed voted here. The decision making process depends on your/your company's goals/budgets/timelines and so on and I don't believe anyone here can answer this question better than you or your management. You seem to be on the right track, however, you need to perform a feasibility/cost/duration analysis. Best of luck !

Comment: Seems reasonable. I will focus on the latter and maybe have better luck convincing my company on using existing solutions! Thanks!